# Drawing a point in an image in C#

Tags: c#

I have an image with the dimensions of 100x50 and I want to draw a dot in the center - i.e. at 50x25. How would I do this?

Comment: add dot in the image???? what are you actually trying to do mate?

Answer (score 2):

```
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(50, 25, 1, 1));
```

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203733/save-user-drawn-bitmap-graphics-in-c-sharp) for saving the picture

it does not draw on form load so you should add your code in form `paint`event :

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.DarkBlue, new Rectangle(120, 90, 1, 1));
    }
```

Comment: @user1578358 it does my friend I've just tested it, show me your code and I'll tell you where the problem is. Did you named Controls right?

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace chkcenter
{    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {        public Form1()
        {            InitializeComponent();        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.DarkBlue, new Rectangle(120, 90, 1, 1)); } }}

Comment: I stored the image directly in picture box

Comment: @user1578358 you said your picture box is 100x50 but you are using  `new Rectangle(120, 90, 1, 1)` it does not draw because it is outside the bounds of your picture box.

Comment: you should use `new Rectangle(halfOfPictureBoxWidth, halfOfPictureBoxHeight, 1, 1)`

Comment: hey.....  your image dimention?  g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(50, 25, 1, 1));

Comment: Ohhh i see, you can't do it in form load

Comment: do it on `paint` event of form :
            Application.DoEvents();
            Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.DarkBlue, new Rectangle(120, 90, 1, 1));

Comment: it is working for me, have you set the `paint` event of your form?

Comment: how to call that paint event in page load method

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Paint += Form2_Paint;
        }

Answer (score 2):

you could use the [setPixle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx) function.

Comment: when i am trying to call a method it shows an error like Error No overload for method 'SetPixel_Example' takes '0' arguments

Comment: @user1578358 can you send me your code? my mail is: elyashi.horovitz at gmail.com.

Answer (score 2):

```
        Image img = pictureBox1.Image;

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.DarkBlue, new Rectangle(50, 25, 1, 1));

        g.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));

        img.Save("d:\\img.Jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: after draw if you want to show in picture box do :  pictureBox1.Refresh();

Comment: and also i want some code for image capture at particular place.. means in our desktop i want to capture only my-computer folder only using values how it can work on it..   i am already build-ed code for image capture of desktop at particular height and width and also now i want to capture at particular location what the points we are mentioned...

Comment: Hi is it possible what i am mentioned earlier...?

Comment: click the arrow if this is usful for you

Comment: ids it possible what i am mentioned earlier...?

Comment: yes that folder icon and what the thing is there is not a matter i want to capture a image like starting is (1,1) and end the capture at (20,20) like this limits i want to capture a image what is available in desktop..

Comment: upto now i build-ed a capturing code what the desktop contains in particular width and height...

Answer (score 0):

try this for other question :

```
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(10, 20, 50, 60);
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty,Point.Empty, bounds.Size);

        bitmap.Save("d:\\img.Jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

this code will capture screen with bound of bounds rectangle.

Comment: the 20,20  is the dimensions of new image.

Comment: i want to capture our my-computer folder what the folder available in our desktop its the task how to get it...?